# Brew no Git repository. No package formulae showing after install

Tags: macos, homebrew, apple-m1

Picture below shows my issue. In tutorials after install of brew they all show the core with the git revision in brackets but for me my core has no git repository but the cask does, and then when i try to install anything it fails to find all formulae. I am using mac os M1 so unsure if its something to do with the brew install with m1.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try `brew doctor`, it would instruct you how to address this issue.

I think `brew update` would solve the issue.